# Проверка хоста C#

Tags: c#, .net

Здравстуйте, есть ip-адреса

```
123.123.123.0/24
```

тоесть проверить содержиться ли html страница на адресе `123.123.123.0:80`.

Как это сделать средствами C#

Comment: Отправив ему [WebRequest](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.net.webrequest(v=vs.110).aspx).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуй перебирать ip-адреса в цикле подставляя их в метод:

```
public bool testSite(string url)
{
    Uri uri = new Uri(url);
    try
    {
        HttpWebRequest httpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(uri);
        HttpWebResponse httpWebResponse = (HttpWebResponse)httpWebRequest.GetResponse();
        if (HttpStatusCode.OK == httpWebResponse.StatusCode)
        {
            // HTTP = 200 - страница есть
            httpWebResponse.Close();
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
           // сервер вернул отрицательный ответ
            httpWebResponse.Close();
            return false;
        }
    }
    catch (WebException)
    {
        // Ошибка, интернета нет
        return false;
    }
}
```